# Ignore View controllers from XCTest coverage

Tags: swift, unit-testing, code-coverage, xctest

I am making my first go to the unit testing. I am using MVVM and i can test pretty much everything with unit test (not ui test). The problem is that in the coverage my controller classes are showing up and that affect my coverage. Off course i can always do UI testing to cover those classes but i do not want. Is it possible to ignore from coverage all the classes that `import UIKit` ?

Comment: I recommend unit testing All The Things, including view controllers. If I were on your team, I would want to at least be able to see your lack of coverage on view controllers. Whether you unit test them or not, don't hide the truth.

Comment: It is not suposed to hide them. But i know that my controllers do not have anything except ViewModel calls. I can always test them using UI tests.

Comment: Ah, very nice. What about view snapshot tests, to confirm layout hasn't changed? (Those don't have to be at the view controller level, but often are.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (yet).

But Code Coverage is not a useful metric. You can increase the coverage without improving your test suite. You should ignore that number. Write tests until you are confident that a test run where all tests pass means that the app works.

Alternatively, write tests for your view controllers.

Comment: Another question: What is the metric for good code? If you have one, maybe that also fits to test code. I don't have such a metric. Not for code. Not for test code.